# how to find a amount of variables in visual stidio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

i need to see a amount of variable in visual studio 2013 ?
and i cant find this menu in below visual studio ?
Debug -> Windows -> Locals while running the solution
thanks for help

Comment: What do you mean with "amount of variables?" their values?

Comment: yes exactly. i cant see variable !!!